# How to fetch a property only if it's not null in Hibernate

Tags: hql, jpql

In Hibernate query how do i check if a property is null? Depending on the result i want to fetch that property and if it is not null i have to fetch another property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following two ways are valid HQL queries and both are also valid JPA 2.0 JPQL queries.

Using coalesce (returns first non-null, or null if both are null):

```
SELECT coalesce(e.property, e.otherProperty) FROM SomeEntity e
```

Equivalent select-case, which is bit longer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN e.property IS NULL THEN e.otherProperty ELSE e.property END 
FROM SomeEntity e
```